# How to open hyperlinks in excel in order using chrome

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a code to open hyperlinks from an excel sheet in chrome. it works just fine, however I have noticed a strange behavior, it opens the hyperlinks not in from up t down order but using some criteria I don't understand it's not randomly because when testing I noticed it always opened the links in tha same order i.e

Hyperlink 1
Hyperlink 2
Hyperlink 3
Hyperlink 4
Hyperlink 5

It would always open

Hyperlink 2 Hyperlink 1 Hyperlink 3 Hyperlink 4 Hyperlink 5

Everytime I ran the code it open them in that order I need it to open the hyperlinks in a top to bottom order. Here is the code

```
Sub Open_HyperLinks()
    Dim chromePath As String, hl As Hyperlink

    chromePath = Environ("PROGRAMFILES(X86)") & "\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
 If Selection.Count > 1 Then
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
 End If
    'On Error Resume Next
    For Each hl In Selection.Hyperlinks
        Shell chromePath & " -url " & hl.Address
      Next hl
End Sub
```

Comment: Where/how are the URLs stored? In a single cell? I one row or one column? Is Chrome closed when you run your code?

Comment: Each hyperlink is stored in a single cell, for example hyperlink 1 is in cell A1 hyperlink 2 cell A2 and so on... chrome is open

Answer (score 0):

[Don't use `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros), as it can cause issues.

Does this work for you?

```
Sub Open_HyperLinks()
Dim chromePath As String, hl As Hyperlink
Dim rng As Range, visRng As Range

chromePath = Environ("PROGRAMFILES(X86)") & "\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

Set rng = Selection

If rng.Count > 1 Then
    Set visRng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End If
'On Error Resume Next
For Each hl In visRng.Hyperlinks

    Shell chromePath & " -url " & hl.Address
Next hl
End Sub
```

Comment: Nope still not opening them in order I wonder if what I'm trying to do is possible I tried `Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01")` but still same behaviour